# Apache Camel Xpath 2.0 with Saxon does not look to work in RouteBuilder / Predicates

Tags: xpath, apache-camel, saxon, xpath-2.0

I am using ServiceMix 4.5.3 which includes Camel 2.10.7 and I am able to make XSLT 2.0 transformations with the Saxon library using the option endpoint like this:

```
...
to("xslt:stylesheet.xsl?transformerFactoryClass=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl")
...
```

However when I try to use the xpath function like this:

```
private Namespaces ourNS = new Namespaces("myns",
        "urn:com:company:domain:namespace:myns/1");

// ... some code ...

// Make a predicate to filter according a header : 
// The code attribute looks like: urn:phone:apple:iphone:4s
Predicate isNotSamePhoneBrand = PredicateBuilder.isNotEqualTo(
        xpath("tokenize(/myns:Phone/@code, ':')[3]").namespaces(ourNS),
        header("PhoneBrand"));
```

If I execute the above code it says the tokenize() function is unknown. I guess it is because it still uses xalan (xpath 1.0) instead Saxon.

I also tried as well to append the .saxon() as in the Camel documentation

```
Predicate isNotSamePhoneBrand = PredicateBuilder.isNotEqualTo(
        xpath("tokenize(/myns:Phone/@code, ':')[3]").namespaces(ourNS).saxon(),
        header("PhoneBrand"));
```

But it makes an error that he cannot find the Saxon implementation factory:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: No XPathFctory implementation found for the object model: http://saxon.sf.net/jaxp/xpath/om
```

In my OSGI context I verified that both `camel-saxon` and `Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: saxon9he (9.3.0.11_2)` are deployed.

We are planning to upgrade to ServiceMix 5 soon but I do not know if this problem is still there or not, a solution for the version 4.5.3 would be better for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a working solution for the camel route:

As the .saxon() was without effect on my route, I decided to look another way and I found there is a specific option to override the Xpath factory like this:

```
.factory(new net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl())
```

After that I had to force the conversion of the result of the Xpath into a String with `.resultType(String.class)`.

The full predicate will looks like this:

```
Predicate isNotSamePhoneBrand = PredicateBuilder.isNotEqualTo(
        xpath("tokenize(/myns:Phone/@code, ':')[3]").namespaces(ourNS)
        .factory(new net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl()).resultType(String.class),
        header("PhoneBrand"));
```

and now the tokenize function (xpath 2.0) is very well recognized.

I found that I have to do the same thing with the instantiation of the factory implementation when I use it in a camel Processor like this:

```
net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl factory = new net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

NodeList channels = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(
    "//*:Channels/*:Channel/text()",
    body, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

This is not dynamic but I want to force the usage of Saxon everywhere then this solution fit our needs.

Answer (score 3):

In Saxon 9.6 we removed the services file that registered Saxon as an implementation of the JAXP XPathFactory interface. It still implements that interface, it just doesn't have a services file in the JAR file manifest that says so. There's a long history behind this, but there are basically two main reasons: (a) incompatibility between JDK releases making it impossible to produce a services file that works from JDK 5 to JDK 8 inclusive, and (b) merely putting Saxon on the classpath was causing applications to break if they were not written or tested to work with XPath 2.0.

I guess there's a workaround by adding the services file to the SAXON Jar file manifest yourself (you can copy it from the 9.5 release).

Comment: Ok, then it looks more a problem with classpath of the JVM than a specific problem in ServiceMix. That would explain why sometime it is working in Junit (Eclipse JVM) but not in integration testing (SMX JVM). I am going to find a solution but not yet sure if it does work or not.

Comment: Ah a just notice the version you're talking about. But i think we have the 9.3.0.11_2 as written in the SMX console. as you say, we should be able to use the services before the 9.6. but it does not seems to work as-is.

Comment: What JDK version are you using? It's known that the services file which we used to include doesn't work with JDK 8.

Comment: we're using JDK 7 (me under centos 6.5 and my colleagues under windows 7... but same effects on both platforms)

Comment: Thanks for you post, it helps me to find the proper solution (see my answer)