# How to get Camel to use Saxon for an xpath choice predicate?

Tags: xpath, apache-camel, saxon

In a route I build with Talend 6.5, the Saxon 9.5 jar was used, and so all XPath predicates were evaluated using Saxon.

Having upgraded to Talend 7.1 in order to use the newer Camel versions, now the saxon 9.8 version is used, and I understand from ([Apache Camel Xpath 2.0 with Saxon does not look to work in RouteBuilder / Predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322554/apache-camel-xpath-2-0-with-saxon-does-not-look-to-work-in-routebuilder-predic)) that 9.6+ isn't used automatically.

Ideally, I'd like Saxon to be used for all xslt/xpath evaluation in Camel, while I can use the `saxon=true` modifier for the XSLT component, but I can't figure out how to use it with a choice predicate.

I have something like

```
from("direct:start")
...
.choice()
.when()
.xpath("myXpath2String")
...
.endChoice()
...
```

I've tried adding a `.saxon()` after the `xpath(...)` clause, but that doesn't work.

Surely there is a way of doing this, but nothing I've tried works.

Can anyone suggest a suitable way of forcing the predicate to used Saxon? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to ask the Talend support team for commercial help

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to this issue - somewhat ugly, but it works.

Reading through the Javadoc of the Camel BuilderSupport and Expression, it seems that the `.saxon()` modifier doesn't work against an expression `.xpath` as it doesn't return an XpathBuilder object. However, as the `.when()` can take an expression as a parameter itself, using the BuilderSupport form of `xpath()` returns an XPathBuilder object and thus supports the `.saxon()` modifier.

However, Talend does not appear to be able to allow you to supply a parameter to the `.when` function, but only apply expression qualifiers afterwards.

In order to get around this, I have the following structure:

[image: Picture of Talend Route]

The criteria of the "Criteria" link is set to a constant expression of `"false"`. This is followed by a cJavaDSLProcessor component with the code of the form:

```
.when(xpath("myXPath2Expression").saxon())
```

and this works, albeit by having an unused criteria in the resultant `.choice()` which is certainly bad style.